# UIkit Tableview cell color is correct when selected but then color disappears

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a custom cell which I have provided a custom colour for. When I select/tap the cell the cell goes blue but then the colour clears. I would like the selected cell to remain blue when selected.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return siteFilterArr.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "siteCell", for: indexPath) as? siteTableViewCell else{
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Blue")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        
        cell.configure(with: siteFilterArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        //Have the user selected in memory
        PassCompanyOffice = siteFilterArr[indexPath.row].siteName!
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All that was to be removed was:

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)